# How to split this "#123/200$345/400%" into 123/200 and 345/400 as output using re.split funtion in python

Tags: python, regex

```
text = '#123/200$345/400%'

print(re.split('#|/|$|%',text))
```

I have tried the above code but it doesn't work so anyone can help. Thank you in advance. I have Mentioned input as well as output requirements.

My Req:

```
Input= "#123/200$345/400%" 

Output1=("123/200","345/400")
```

Comment: Regex will help u

Comment: I'm not sure you need `re` here; what values of `text` would break `text.strip('#%').split("$")`?

Answer (score 2):

Regex split() can take any number of single-character delimiters inside `[]`:

```
>>> print(re.split(r'[#$%]',text))
['', '123/200', '345/400', '']
```

Splitting by those characters will obviously generate blank strings (before the first delimiter and after the last), so you can filter them out:

```
>>> print([part for part in re.split(r'[#$%]',text) if part])
['123/200', '345/400']
```

It seems forward slash (`/`) is not one of your desired delimiters.

Edit: as pointed out by @Avinash Raj, inside `[]` there is no need to escape chars.

Comment: no need to escape chars which exists inside char class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex.

**Code:**

```
text = '#123/200$345/400%'
print(text.replace("#", "").replace("%", "").split("$"))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python split_test.py 
['123/200', '345/400']
```

If you really need `tuple` type, you can do:

**Code:**

```
text = '#123/200$345/400%'
print(tuple(text.replace("#", "").replace("%", "").split("$")))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python split_test.py 
('123/200', '345/400')
```